# Pyspark: how to get Date from Weeknumber and Year

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, week-number

I have a dataframe with a column containing week number and year. For example: `18/2020`, which corresponds to the first date of `2020-04-27`. How can I extract the complete date column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#to_date) with the format [`w/yyyy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "18/2020")], ['id', 'week_year'])
df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("week_year"), "w/yyyy")).show()

#+---+---------+----------+
#| id|week_year|      date|
#+---+---------+----------+
#|  1|  18/2020|2020-04-26|
#+---+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Note that his no longer works in Spark >= 3.0 without adding `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")` (the error will tell you). So far I have not found a proper workaround to this issue with the new time parser.